# Issue with calculating row mean in data table for selected columns in R

Tags: r

I have a data table as shown below.

```
Table:

LP   GMweek1  GMweek2   GMweek3  PMweek1   PMweek2  PMweek3
215   45       50        60       11        0.4     10.2
0.1   50       61        24       12        0.8     80.0
0     45       24        35       22        20.0    15.4
51    22.1     54        13       35        16      2.2
```

I want to obtain the Output table below. My code below does not work. Can somebody help me to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Output:

LP   GMweek1  GMweek2   GMweek3  PMweek1   PMweek2  PMweek3  AvgGM   AvgPM
215   45       50        60       11        0.4     10.2     51.67   7.20
0.1   50       61        24       12        0.8     80.0     45.00   30.93
0     45       24        35       22        20.0    15.4     34.67   19.13
51    22.1     54        13       35        16      2.2      29.70   17.73

sel_cols_GM <- c("GMweek1","GMweek2","GMweek3")
sel_cols_PM <- c("PMweek1","PMweek2","PMweek3")

Table <- Table[, .(AvgGM = rowMeans(sel_cols_GM)), by = LP]
Table <- Table[, .(AvgPM = rowMeans(sel_cols_PM)), by = LP]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so you're doing a couple of things wrong. First, `rowMeans` can't evaluate a character vector, if you want to select columns by using it you must use `.SD` and pass the character vector to `.SDcols`. Second, you're trying to calculate a row aggregation and grouping, which I don't think makes much sense. Third, even if your expression didn't throw an error, you are assigning it back to `Table`, which would destroy your original data (if you want to add a new column use `:=` to add it by reference).

What you want to do is calculate the row means of your selected columns, which you can do like this:

```
Table[, AvgGM := rowMeans(.SD), .SDcols = sel_cols_GM] 
Table[, AvgPM := rowMeans(.SD), .SDcols = sel_cols_PM]
```

This means create these new columns as the row means of my subset of data (`.SD`) which refers to these columns (`.SDcols`)